# Has Android 6 Update Caused PC Connection Issues for Galaxy Note 4?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-4

Since updating my Samsung Galaxy Note 4 to version 6 of the Marshmallow operating system, it won't show up when I connect it to my PC.  Any recommendations? Is anyone else having a problem?  It may NOT be related to the Android update -- but I've never had this issue before.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you changed the USB settings on the phone from just charging to mtp?

Pull down the notification bar while it is plugged in and select the USB notification followed by Mtp which is just file transfer.

Some info on that:
http://m.androidcentral.com/inside-marshmallow-usb-connection-options

Comment: Thank you so much!  That got it!  The key wasn't going to Settings / Notifications -- it was actually swiping down on the Notifications screen.  I am so grateful for your response.

Comment: Glad to help! If the answer was accurate, would you mind just marking it as correct so the thread doesn't stay open. Thanks!

Comment: You bet!  I will be happy to mark your answer as correct, just tell me how.  I'm new to this forum, but there was nothing in the Q&A search instructing me on how to do it!  Not seeing any "mark answer as correct," etc.

Comment: @KipKirby underneath the up and down arrows on the answer there should be a check. Just hit that. Thanks!

Comment: Boy, they don't make THAT very clear, do they?!  :-)  Anyway, I followed your instructions and the check mark turned green, so I take that as a positive sign!  LOL.  Thanks again.  I'm sure this won't be my last question here in the forum, but you were the only one to answer, and you solved my problem perfectly.  Thanks so much!